# How to make last column of a table as the same width as of other columns

Tags: html, firefox, html-table, width, multiple-columns

I have a table with 5 columns. I want the last column to have the same width as the rest of columns. I am using Mozilla Firefox as the browser to test the html page. I have given the table width and also the column widths (td) in %. I see that the first 4 column take the width given but the last column doesn't. Help needed.

Answer (score 0):

here is you make the mistake..
See this example in images..
and try this..

[image]

I 100% sure you got exact remaining width..